# Regex pattern to allow any ASCII chars. But not leading white spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have to add a validation to a text box by writing a regex.

- Characters can be any ASCII chars including special chars.
- But it should not allow space or only spaces.
- There can be spaces in between words and can also be a leading space.

I know "`[^\s]`" to validate for space.
I know  "`^[\x00-\x7F]+$`" to validate for ASCII Chars.

I want to combine these things to say i will allow ASCII chars including space but not just space or spaces.

Is there any way to do **AND** operation on this? or How to proceed?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the case of  a word after a space, i should not trim the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
^(?> *)[\x00-\x7F]+$
```

Since the eventual leading spaces are enclosed in an atomic group, you can be sure that the first character matched by `[\x00-\x7F]+` can't be a space.

Comment: Why? How did you understand the question? It has self-contradictory requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have made abstraction of the title.

Comment: @NJMR: You should rewrite your title to make your requirements more clear.